# Is there a better way to change title and meta tags than ob_get_contents();?

Tags: php

I have a website with over 5.000 articles and over 100 different "info-pages". I have always just fetched the title and other information from the database and placed a query in the header, depending on which page the user was on. But... I now have around 4.000 pageviews per day and thats a lot of "extra" calls to the database.

I have now tried this:

in the top of the index.php file:

```
<?php
ob_start (); // Buffer output
?>
<head>
    <title>%TITLE%</title>
    <meta name="description" content="%META%">
</head>
```

In the bottom of the index.php file:

```
<?php
$pageContents = ob_get_contents (); // Get all the page's HTML into a string
ob_end_clean (); // Wipe the buffer

if(!isset($pageTitle)) {
    $pageTitle = "Default title";
}
if(!isset($pageMeta)) {
    $pageMeta = "Default meta description";
}

$healthy = ["%TITLE%","%META%"];
$yummy   = [$pageTitle, $pageMeta];

echo str_replace($healthy, $yummy, $pageContents);
?>
```

All other .php files:

```
...
    $pageTitle = "Title of this exact php page";
    $pageMeta = "Meta of this exact php page";
...
```

I don't know why, but I feel there must be a way to do this that is easier and more sufficient.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you please add the relevant database access and fetch data code please?

Comment: try using a template engine like platesphp or twig. then you can do all your logic first, then send to your templates. http://platesphp.com/